# Web Service contract without implementation specific information

Tags: wcf, web-services, wsdl, contract

I have to define a web service contract that afterwards will be used by different software suppliers to implement their servers and clients.

I tried to do it defining classes, making a WCF service and using it to autogenerate WSDL document. The problem with this approach is that inside WSDL there are some specifics concerning binding and the web service address.

How to achieve generating a web service contract without such implementation specific information?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Łukasz Głaz

Comment: What happens if you host the service in a host that only supports mexHttpBinding, and no other bindings?

Comment: It didn't work. Svcutil.exe protested and not generated any metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that using namespaces appropriately it is possible to autogenerate abstract parts of the server definition into one WSDL file and one XSD file and the implementation specific parts (binding and service elements) into another WSDL file. In this way I get the separation I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the absolute best way to do this would be to not generate the WSDL at all - create it by hand. Generate your various contract classes *from* the WSDL, and use those to implement the service.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will use the idea when I will be doing my next web service.